# Reference for understanding coalgebra

Tags: reference-request, universal-algebra, coalgebras

I am trying to read [this](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~janr/papers/files-of-papers/universal_coalgebra.pdf) paper, but I have no knowledge of coalgebra and have just started to learn Category Theory so I am struggling to understand it.

Are there any references that can explain coalgebra more simply to someone who has little to no knowledge of category theory and no knowledge of universal algebra and coalgebra?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalgebra) isn't that bad, I think.

Comment: Majid's book "Foundations of quantum group theory" comes with an introduction to coalgebras and bialgebras. It's not very hard on the category theory.

Comment: I think http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-coalgebra is more relevant to the kind of coalgebra used in the linked paper. There are some links there that may be helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 references:

- "[Quantum Groups](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Quantum_Groups.html?id=S1KE_pToY98C&redir_esc=y)", Kassel
- "[Algebraic Operads](http://math.unice.fr/~brunov/Operads.pdf)", Loday & Vallette

The book by Kassel is very well written and contains an expository part on algebras / coalgebras with modules / comodules as well. The second reference is an advanced book on algebraic structures called operads. Chapter I ("Algebras, coalgebras, homology")
contains, in particular, an introduction to coalgebras.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest: 
[Hopf algebras: an introduction](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Hopf_Algebra.html?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&redir_esc=y), Sorin Dascalescu, Constantin Nastasescu, Serban Raianu

It starts from the "ground" and the first chapters introduce the basic notions with minimal prerequisites (mainly linear algebra, and a first couse in abstract algebra). It emphasizes on structures and costructures over fields and its first chapters elaborate on the duality between algebras and coalgebras and the motivations for the introduction of the definitions. Contains a wealth of examples and detailed calculations. It also covers the elementary notions of Category theory in a separate and well-written appendix.